# Javascript decimal rounding & global variable trouble

Tags: javascript, forms

Im building a checkout form. The following code sets the quantity from a form select box and the bottom one gives me the basic Sub Total , Tax and Total.  This works fine.  Though I’m sure its not the best code.

```
<!------QUANTITY CALCULATIONS & REALTIME UPDATE CODE---------->
    function calQuantity(){
    var units=0;

    var paymentForm = document.forms["payment_form_id"];

    var v_quantity = paymentForm.elements["quantity"]; 
    <!--NEED TO CHANGE IF PRICE CHANGES --> 
    units = v_quantity.value*19.99;

    return units;
}

<!------SUBTOTAL - TAX - TOTAL CALCULATIONS & REALTIME UPDATE CODE----->        
function calSubTotal(){
    var subT = calQuantity();
    var sub_obj = document.getElementById('sub_id');  
    sub_obj.innerHTML = subT;

    var tax = document.getElementById('tax_id'); 
    var tax = tax.innerHTML = subT * 0.06;

    var total = document.getElementById('total_id'); 
    var total = total.innerHTML = subT + tax;

     document.write (subT);
     document.write (tax);
     document.write (total);

}
```

**Two problems:**

1st I need to make those 3 VARS (subT,tax,total) round decimal to 2 places I.E. ($5.56) – I have seen many ways to do this, most very involved,  but I can’t seem to incorporate into my code.  I was thinking of some simple way to have all of them run through a single function and output correctly.

2nd Problem – In this line:
    var tax = tax.innerHTML = subT * 0.06;

I need that 0.06 (Tax rate) to be added from another form.  I was trying to get it into a global VAR, I thought it would be simple, but isn’t working.  It’s a SELECT ele that chooses a state. Value holds the proper sales tax for that state.  There is a form submitted before this final payment info form.   I can generate and put the proper value into a VAR in that form.  I just can’t get that local VAR over to these functions. 
Thanks

Comment: 1. `var tax = parseFloat((subT * 0.06).toFixed(2));`  
2. If you have tax rate on the server side (from previous request) just add it to your code `var taxRate = <?php echo $taxrate; ?>;`

Comment: Thanks. 1st works good...2nd would work except the var is being used in a function and putting the PHP inside is breaking it.  I have been looking at some answers like this:     var BTS = <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($BILLTOSTATE));?>; But still no luck